# After update, can see connections, but can't connect

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu

Recently I installed Lubuntu and everything was fine until I updated it.
Suddenly I lost connection to the internet and I can't connect since (but connection was fine for a few minutes after rebooting right after updating). I can see my network but when I click to connect nothing is happening.
I've tried to look for solution, but nothing worked.

I'll be very greatfull for any help or advice.

Here's some information which I think are usefull (based on my research).

My system: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If you need any more information, please tell me.

Wireless script result:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7510836/

I want to add that I have Windows 7 also on this machine and I don't have any problem with wireless.
Also, I've tried running Lubuntu directly from CD and I had no problem with connection aswell.
The problem started after updating system.

And also, the problem started right after installing gcc, but I don't think that's connected :)

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>